# can't login in GUI of ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, login-screen

I have done extensive search for the answer to this problem:

On the login in page, after tying password, my screen turns dark for a second and becomes the login page again. the guest account doesn't work either.

what I have done:
in tty1:

```
sudo rm /home/wks-403/.Xauthority
sudo reboot
```

or

in tty1:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME
Then press CTRL+ALT+F7 and try to log in
```

or change from lightdm to gdm, in tty1:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

but none works on my laptop.

the parameters of my laptop:
thinkpad x-61 32bit
graphic card: Intel Corp. Mobile GM965/GL960 integrated Graphics Controller

## Thanks for your suggestions!!

update by suggestions from 'Still a kid',

input "sudo startx"

```
Fatal server error
Sever is already active for display 0
If this server is no longer running , remove /tem/.X0-lock

please consult the THe X.Org Foundation support for help

ddxSigGiveUp: Closing Log
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 KEYInvalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Resource temporarily unavailable
xinit: server error
```

I delete `/tmp/.X0-lock` and `startx`

```
cannot establish any listening sockets -Make sure an X server sin't already running
```

I am lost on what to do...please help.

The following is the info in `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5697791/
I notice there is messages saying 'Greeter quit', so I look at `/var/log/x-0-greeter.log`:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5697781/
there are warnings and CRITICAL info.

I suspect this is due to graphic cards, but It doesn't help after I updating my graphic card drivers.

Comment: did you try startx command?

Comment: It sounds as if your X server is running, but there are errors in attempting to log you into an X session. Please review /var/log/Xorg.0.log and include any errors relevant to the problem.
In order to get a good look at what exactly is happening you may want to use tty1-6 to monitor Xorg.0.log, or the log of your desktop manager whether it be lightdm or gdm ... when you see the login prompt use _ctrl+alt+F1_ to move to tty1, then follow the log with _tail -f /var/log/Xorg.0.log_ or the appropriate lightdm or gdm log

Comment: @OYRM thanks. /var/log/Xorg.0.log is very long and i can't find any error logs(i searched for EE keyword). i am using lightgm by setting "sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm"(by the way, using gdm doesn't help).

Comment: Sure thing @ulyssis2 please similarly check all logs in /var/log/lightdm/ and let me know what you see there

Comment: @OYRM I scan through lightdm.log, it is pretty long, and i paste it in another answer.

Comment: you do have a section of that which repeats while attempting to login. Search for _DEBUG: Starting local X display_ and you'll see that it's repeated over the course of 40 lines, with those lines showing a failure to start the lightdm session for user "di", though the authentication for "di" appears to work

*Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log* indicates to me that you may be able to find more information in that file. In short there is something serious failing when you try to start your lightdm session. You will need to keep following the logs, check out Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log

Comment: @ulyssis2 please see the answer above, forgot to tag it for you

Comment: @ulyssis2 did you stop X first ? If you move to tty1 by using "ctrl+alt+F1" or another tty in a similar manner, then you haven't stopped the X server. In order to stop the X server, use "sudo stop lightdm" from the terminal. But wait! You aren't having trouble starting X, you are having trouble logging into lightdm. I mentioned before that you should look int /var/log/lightdm and investigate the logs in that directory. Have you done so ?

Comment: @ulyssis2 Please don't post logs as answers. These are not answers to your question and will be deleted. Copy and paste the log files in [Paste Ubuntu](http://www.paste.ubuntu.com/) and add the links to your original question above.

Comment: start your ubuntu in repair mode and try it to repair

Comment: @OYRM sorry for long delay. I update my thread with the info on the log files.

Comment: @ulyssis2 I get 404 errors at both of those links. So, we're not making much progress. If you can get those logs to me we can continue. However, also, please login, stop the lightdm session, clear your ~/.xsession-errors file, start lightdm again, and then attempt to login through the greeter and get me that .xsession-errors file as well.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this? I'm having the same issue I think.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this, check this [link](http://www.x.org/wiki/FAQErrorMessages#I_keep_getting_the_message%3a_.22Server_is_already_active_for_display_0.22)

```
    rm -rf /tmp/.X0-lock
```